# Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError When add Polyline to google map

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I have an application that tracks location when moving, every 5 sec I send the broadcast receiver to draw a polyline in google map, I use the method below:

```
    ArrayList<Location> locationList = Service.locationList;

    if (locationList.size() == 2) {
        Location fromLocation = locationList.get(0);
        Location toLocation = locationList.get(1);

        LatLng from = new LatLng(((fromLocation.getLatitude())),
                ((fromLocation.getLongitude())));

        LatLng to = new LatLng(((toLocation.getLatitude())),
                ((toLocation.getLongitude())));

        polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(from, to)
                .width(10).color(Color.parseColor("#801B60FE")).geodesic(true));

    } else if (locationList.size() > 2 && polyline.getPoints()!=null) {
        Location toLocation = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
        LatLng to = new LatLng(((toLocation.getLatitude())),
                ((toLocation.getLongitude())));

           points = polyline.getPoints();
            points.add(to);
            polyline.setPoints(points);

    }
```

After some time it causes OOM :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>       Failed to allocate a 603979784 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 197MB until OOM
>
> java.util.Arrays.copyOf (Arrays.java:3352)
>
> java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity (AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
>   com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run (NetworkDispatcher.java:87)

Can anyone give me a solution ??

Comment: keep a handle to the previous polyline and remove it before plotting a new one.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, actually its one polyline, but every 5 sec it become more bigger, I need the entire polyline

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to allocate an array that has more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements in this line. You can not allocate more than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
ArrayList<Location> locationList = Service.locationList;
```

Check the size of Service.locationList

Comment: locationList is an ArrayList, there is no MAX_VALUE for it, I'm using it to store location from service every 5 sec.

Comment: Can you debug the size of this array? Your array size is exceeding than Integer.MAX_VALUE which should not be happened. ArrayList is accessible using index integer value and integer value has limit of Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: this would be `2^31-1` which equals `2147483647`... multiplied with `5s`.

Comment: oh, I think this is my problem, it stores more than 2147483647 location in the array list, what do you think the best solution to this problem? making another array for example ?

Answer (score 0):

use [PolyUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html) method `.simplyfy()` to handle the memory utilization more conservatively.

here's the [repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution.

Comment: you could possibly `extend Polyline` and add a method to add a verticle - because `.getPoints()` returns a snapshot of the current points, which doubles up the memory utilization for a moment. it's unfortunate that `Polyline` does not have such a method by default.

Answer (score 0):

Create Global variable of List of LatLng,
ArrayList alData =new ArrayList<>();

on your broadcast receiver add below code,

```
LatLng position = new LatLng(((ocation.getLatitude())),
                ((location.getLongitude())));
        alData.add(position);

        if (polyline!=null)polyline.remove();

        polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(alData));
```